# pass values from one form to the dropdown list in other form

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a drop down list in one webform that takes it's values from the submission data of other webform. How can I pass the submission data on one form to the drop down list in the other ..

Many thanks.

Comment: are both forms on the same page?

Comment: No,two separate forms in two separate pages @geoff